# cppcheck null pointer dereference: m_buffer - otherwise it is redundant to check it against null

Tags: c++, cppcheck

the code is working properly but when i checked it on cppcheck i found the null pointer dereferenc error i couldnt understand how to solve it. any thoughts would be appreciated

here is the part of code that i got the error

```
#ifdef DEBUG_LEVEL_MID
    std::clog << "STARTING FUNCTION int ConfigurationType::ExecuteMessageType()" << std::endl;
    std::clog << "message with code : " << message_to_execute->code << "will be tried o executed" << std::endl;
    #endif    

    if(!message_to_execute)
    {
        #ifdef DEBUG_LEVEL_ERROR
        std::cerr << "message_to_execute is null at: int ConfigurationType::ExecuteMessageType()" << std::endl;
        #endif    
        #ifdef DEBUG_LEVEL_MID
        std::clog << "message_to_execute is NULL at int ConfigurationType::ExecuteMessageType()" << std::endl;
        std::clog << "ENDING FUNCTION (0): int ConfigurationType::ExecuteMessageType()" << std::endl;
        #endif    
        return 0;
    }
```

the error is :  Possible null pointer dereference: message_to_execute - otherwise it is redundant to check it against null.

Comment: You already have a correct [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29748215/96780), but this DEBUG_LEVEL stuff seems overcomplicated and error prone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You dereference `message_to_execute` here: `std::clog << "message with code : " << message_to_execute->code`.

This means that the `if (!message_to_execute)` later is redundant because you are not allowed to dereference a null pointer, therefore the compiler is allowed to assume that `message_to_execute` is not null, and remove the test.

Answer (score 2):

You are already accessing the pointer before you check if it is valid: `message_to_execute->code`. Move this into the if statement and the warning will be gone.

CPPCheck is right, if it is a nullptr it will be a nullptr dereference and if it is not you will be checking if it is?

Comment: thanks i solved it but there is sth else similar i am dealing with i will post it and will appreciate your thoughts if couldnt remove the bug

Comment: @user3521035 please mark this answer as the accepted answer and then post a new question containing that specific scenario (as it is probably a different question). :)